# xlsxwirter merge_range with URL

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

How to write a text with `merge_range` using Xlsxwriter in python and put a hyperlink without change the cell format defined at

```
wks.merge_range(, , , ,  'text', format)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the url is one of the standard one recognised by `write()` then `merge_range()` will turn it into a hyperlink. The format will be whatever you define:

```
import xlsxwriter

# Create an new Excel file and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('merge_url.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

# Set up a formats to use.
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center',
                                   'color': 'blue',
                                   'underline': 1,
                                   'valign': 'vcenter',
                                   'border': 1})

worksheet.merge_range('B2:E5', 'https://www.python.org/', cell_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image: merged url]

If you want to have a link but with alternative text you can overwrite the first cell of the range with the text and same format like this:

```
worksheet.write_url('B2', 'https://www.python.org/', cell_format, 'text')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Works fine. Just the presentation at LibreOffice 6.1 appear wrong. This issue was reported to the develop team.